# Why does this generic method implementation NOT require the Type value to be passed?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression

I have implemented a strongly typed implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, except instead of using the interface, I have added a base class to implement.

It works fine, but the bit I am struggling with is why TValue is used in the base method declaration (I did use this section from some code I found online)

`NotifyPropertyUpdate<TValue>(`...

BUT in the derived class, it doesn't need to pass `TValue` at all!

What tells the compiler to resolve this at runtime instead of complaining at build?

Thanks,

Base class:

```
public class NotifyFuncPropertyChanged<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyUpdate<TValue>(Expression<Func<T, TValue>> selector)
    {
        //get memberInfo from object selection
        MemberInfo memberInfoSelection;
        Expression body = selector;
        if (body is LambdaExpression)
        {
            body = ((LambdaExpression)body).Body;
        }
        switch (body.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                memberInfoSelection =((MemberExpression)body).Member;
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        //send notifyupdate to memberInfo
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(memberInfoSelection.Name));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Usage (derived class)

```
public class NameTest : NotifyFuncPropertyChanged<NameTest>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void TestUpdateName()
    {
        this.NotifyPropertyUpdate(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C# compiler has a feature called **Type inference**. You can read about it in all its complexity in [the language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7029), in section 7.5.2, or there's a very brief introduction [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb).

From the spec:

> When a generic method is called without specifying type arguments, a
>   **type inference** process attempts to infer type arguments for the call. The presence of type inference allows a more convenient syntax
>   to be used for calling a generic method, and allows the programmer to
>   avoid specifying redundant type information. For example, given the
>   method declaration:
>
> ```
> class Chooser
> {
>   static Random rand = new Random();
>   public static T Choose<T>(T first, T second) {
>       return (rand.Next(2) == 0)? first: second;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> it is possible to invoke the `Choose` method without explicitly
>   specifying a type argument:
>
> ```
> int i = Chooser.Choose(5, 213);                   // Calls Choose<int>
> string s = Chooser.Choose("foo", "bar");      // Calls Choose<string>
> ```
>
> Through type inference, the type arguments `int` and `string` are
>   determined from the arguments to the method.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can automatically deduce `TValue` from the argument. In effect, the calling line compiles as:

```
this.NotifyPropertyUpdate<string>(x => x.Name);
```

You can see this same thing happening when you call pretty much any LINQ extension method.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler infers the type of `TValue`. It still happens at compile time, not at runtime.

You pass in the following lambda: `x => x.Name`. The compiler knows that `Name` is of type `string` and thus `TValue` is `string`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but HOW does the compiler know? Is it on the type text 'TValue' - what happens if i changed it to 'TrainStation'?

Comment: The name of the generic argument is irrelevant. How the compiler knows I explained in my answer. If anything is unclear, please ask.

Comment: I guess the bit I am not getting is why the compiler reconciles TValue in this scenario. Is it because the method parameter signature is of type 'Expression'? Again this raises issues such as, what happens when I ALSO want to pass in a type to the base method. (I have just tried this out, and it means the compiler stops infering the lambda type) - i just find it quite confusing behavior

Comment: @Patrick: The compiler will always try to infer all generic type parameters on any generic method, regardless of the parameter types. There are no "magic markers" involved. Conversely, you always have the option of overriding this and explicitly specifying the generic types at the call site.